# Neo4j APOC containsAny

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

There is APOC `apoc.coll.containsAll` function https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.coll/apoc.coll.containsAll/  But do we have something like `containsAny`? If no, what should be used instead? I have two sets and would like to check if the first set contains any value from the second set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need `APOC` for this.

Please try this:

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE any(element IN n.firstList WHERE element IN n.secondList)
RETURN n
```

Example on real values:

```
WITH [4,5,6,7] as second, [1,2,3,4] as first
RETURN ANY(element IN first WHERE element IN second)
```

Comment: Thank you! I hope `any` is smart enough to stop execution after the first match and not walk through the entire collection after that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use APOC, you can use intersection:

```
RETURN size(apoc.coll.intersection([1,2,3,4,5], [3,6,9]))>0 AS containsAny

will return TRUE


RETURN size(apoc.coll.intersection([1,2,3,4,5], [6,9]))>0 AS containsAny

will return FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you! One possible issue with intersection that I'm thinking of is that it potentially will evaluate the entire collections… but I'm fighting with the performance issue and would like something that will stop execution after the first match if any